# Using switch in C# to handle all hives

Tags: c#, registry

I was trying to use switch to handle all possibles hives from registry - later on, i want to generate SubKeyNames for key (together with hive) provided as an input, but i still get errors like:
‘A local variable named ‘regKey’ is already defined in this scope’
‘The name ‘regKey’ does not exists in the current context’

```
switch (hive) {  

    case "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT":

                   RegistryKey regKey=Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(key,false);
                   break;                                 

    case "HKEY_CURRENT_USER":

                   RegistryKey regKey=Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key,false);
                   break;  

    case "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE":

                   RegistryKey regKey=Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key,false);
                   break;

    case "HKEY_USERS":

                   RegistryKey regKey=Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(key,false);
                   break;  

    case "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG":

                   RegistryKey regKey=Registry.CurrentConfig.OpenSubKey(key,false);
                   break;  

    default:
        throw new System.Exception("Incorrent hive");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `case` you can try *pattern matching* (you need **c# 8.0**), e.g.

```
RegistryKey regKey = hive switch {
  "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT"   => Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(key, false),
  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"   => Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, false),
  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"  => Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key, false),
  "HKEY_USERS"          => Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(key, false),
  "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG" => Registry.CurrentConfig.OpenSubKey(key, false),
  _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Incorrent hive")
};
```

Or to get rid of pesky `Registry ... OpenSubKey(key, false)` you can move keys to `Dictionary`:

```
private static Dictionary<string, RegistryKey> s_RegRoots = 
  new Dictionary<string, RegistryKey>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    {"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT",   Registry.ClassesRoot},
    {"HKEY_CURRENT_USER",   Registry.CurrentUser},
    {"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE",  Registry.LocalMachine},
    {"HKEY_USERS",          Registry.Users},
    {"HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG", Registry.CurrentConfig},
};

...


RegistryKey regKey = s_RegRoots.TryGetValue(hive, out var root)
  ? root.OpenSubKey(key, false)
  : throw new NotSupportedException("Incorrent hive");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is that you are trying to declare the variable multiply times in the same program I would try moving the creation of the variable to outside your switch structure and then just assign a value to it during the switch structure

Comment: I was also thinking about it, but how to declare empty RegistryKey? Just?
 RegistryKey regKey=new RegistryKey(); (before switch)

Comment: Haven't done much with RegistryKey myself but knew that declaring variable in switch structure doesn't work

Comment: Just put `RegistryKey regKey;` before the switch.  There's no need to initialize it.  That way, if you get to the end of your method and try to use `regKey` the compiler can check that all all of your paths that converge on that use do, in fact, intialize `regKey`

Comment: The lifetime of variables in cases is the switch itself. While rarely useful, and harder to read, you can `goto label` and reuse the same variable.

Comment: @Flydog57 Annoyingly, not possible to do this either.

Comment: @user2924019: I'm not following.  The `RegistryKey` type is a class (i.e. a reference type).  You can definitely declare a variable of that type anywhere.  Something like `RegistryKey regKey; switch (hive) { case "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT":  regKey=Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(key,false); break; /* etc */ default: throw new Excepction(); }`  There's nothing that should prevent that from working.  Of course, a Switch expression (the accepted answer) is probably a better solution